# Mongoid / Rails per-request query count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

We have a production app and we are finding that our biggest bottleneck is db queries.  It's hard to track down exactly what users are doing to figure out what the real world requests are.  We are considering building a per request tracker.  Does Mongoid or Rails support a per-request number of queries tracker? We want something like in development where you can see all the queries fly by, but per request.  We implement this something like this:

application_controller:

```
before_action :log_request_start
after_action :log_request_end

def log_request_start
    request_log = RequestLog.new  # make a new model to 
    request_log.id = Thread.id # use thread?
    request_log.params = request.whatever # harvest some params from the Rails request


def log_request_end
    request_log = Request.find_by(thread_id: Thread.id) #  look it up
    request.total_queries = # can we get the number of mongo queries that fired in this request?
```

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring

Comment: thanks but this doesn't allow per-thread or per-rails-request attribution, so there's no way to know which query came from request x and which came from request y

Comment: You can review https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4631. If you find a mechanism in Rails for reporting/logging query count you are welcome to create a Mongoid ticket requesting integration with that mechanism.

Comment: Have you tried to see if this functionality is available in the mongo database profiler? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/